# how to display google map in popup maker plugin wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, popup

I'm using popup maker to display google maps content. but when i trigger the popup the map doesn't displayed.
when i resize the browser the map content will appear!!
this is example page " [here](http://aranice.com/%D9%86%D9%82%D8%B4%D9%87/) "
I can't find the problem, I use WP google map plugin to generate maps.
please help me, I want to buy this plugin but the issue is stopping me.
best regards

Comment: @B nM  On which page ?  please describe your link

Answer (score 1):

@B nM - Hey there, I'm the author of Popup Maker. The issue is that the map plugin initializes when the page loads and sets the size of the map based on its container. When the popup is hidden its size is effectively 0x0, so that is what is used for the map.

You can use the following to correct it, but adding the correct function from your map plugin will be the most efficient solution.

```
jQuery('.pum').on('pumAfterOpen', function () {
    // If you know the map resize function call it here. Otherwise:
    $(window).trigger('resize');
});
```

Hope that helps.